Symmetrization for the proof of Glivenko-Cantelli property
I am reading the proof of Glivenko-Cantelli property shown in Chapter 4 in "High-Dimensional Statistics A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint". A key step is using Rademacher variables as follows:
Let $(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)$ be an i.i.d. sequence of Rademacher variables, independent of $X$ and $Y$, where $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $Y = (Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ are independently sampled from the same distribution. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a uniformly bounded class of functions, that is, $\exists b>0,$ for any $f\in \mathcal{F}, \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}\le b,$ where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty}$ denotes the sup norm. Then, for any $f\in \mathcal{F},$ the random vector with components $\epsilon_i(f(X_i)-f(Y_i))$ has the
same joint distribution as the random vector with components $f(X_i) - f(Y_i),$ whence
\begin{align}
\mathbb E_{X,Y}\left[ \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\{f(X_i)-f(Y_i)\} \right|\right] &= \mathbb E_{X,Y,\epsilon}\left[ \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\epsilon_i(f(X_i)-f(Y_i)) \right|\right].
\end{align}
I am quite confused about why they have same joint distribution and how this equation holds.
